# Deserializing JSON into generic where collection property name changes based on type

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm working on parsing some API responses using Newtonsoft.Json, and they seem to have a pretty regular structure, except for an array property name that changes based on the return type. A couple response examples (with fake/empty data):

**Customer:**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Records Retrieved Successfully",
  "data": {
    "total_count": "1",
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "accountId": "220",
        "email": "json.voorhees@lycos.com",
        "name": "JSON Voorhees",
        "company": "Test Company",
        "customFieldsValues": [
          {
            "value": "Some Guy",
            "field": {
              "id": "69",
              "name": "SalespersonID",
              "label": "Account Manager"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Invoice:**

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "Records Retrieved Successfully",
  "data": {
    "total_count": "0",
    "invoice": []
  }
}
```

You'll notice in the first one, the property name of the array is "customer", and in the second, it's "invoice" (we don't have any invoices, so I don't know exactly what the structure of that object will be yet).

My end goal is to deserialize into a class structure something like this:

```
public class Response {
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response {
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Since that's not doable directly with a simple `DeserializeObject()` call (because the array of business objects is contained within that intermediate "data" property), this seems like it's a bit closer to what's needed, but the problem is the moving target for the `[JsonProperty()]` attribute:

```
public class Response {
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response {
    public ResponseData Data { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseData<T> {
    [JsonProperty("total_count")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("???")] //Moving target
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

What's the sanest way to pull this off?

Comment: What do you mean by "sanest"?  Your converter [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38791925/3744182) is succinct.  Are you looking for a solution that avoids loading an intermediate representation?

Comment: @dbc Just wondering if there's a better way to do it that doesn't involve first deserializing to a Dictionary, then picking through its guts. If that *is* the simplest way to do it, I can live with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this is working, but it's certainly not the prettiest thing I've ever seen (not totally happy with the intermediate step of converting to a Dictionary). Leaving this question open for now in case somebody knows a better way to do this.

The various objects:

```
public class Response {
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response {
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DataConverter))]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataConverter : JsonConverter {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
        return typeof(List<object>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        Dictionary<string, object> data = (Dictionary<string, object>)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(Dictionary<string, object>));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in data) {
            if (kvp.Key != "total_count") {
                return ((JToken)kvp.Value).ToObject(objectType);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then to fetch the response:

```
public Response<Customer> GetCustomers() {
    string response = SendRequest("/api/v1/customers");
    Response<Customer> aresponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<Customer>>(response);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `JavaScriptDeserializer` object may help you here, as a `dynamic`:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() });

dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
```

Then, get all properties as such to test what properties the object has:

```
var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Then, get the property name you want and pass it in:

```
var value = obj.data[0].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
```

And as an example loop:

```
foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The value for property {0} is {1}.",
        property.Name,
        obj.data[0].GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null));
}
```

Note this answer uses `System.Reflection`, which is painfully slow for large computations (i.e., don't iterate these methods thousands of times unless you have some spare time to kill!)

Comment: Thanks, looks like it might work, though I'd like to avoid reflection if possible, as I don't know how large the data sets will end up being (either in this project, or future ones). Maybe something like that, but walking through a `JsonObject` rather than reflected types?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean when you ask for the "sanest" way to solve this problem.  Json.NET supports [`[JsonExtensionData]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm) for capturing unexpected properties into a `Dictionary<string, object>` or `Dictionary<string, JToken>`.  However, your `List<T> Data` is typed, and Json.NET has nothing built-in that deserializes arbitrarily named properties to typed objects.  You also wrote *not totally happy with the intermediate step of converting to a Dictionary* so it sounds as though you would like a solution that avoids deserializing to an intermediate representation.  The following converter accomplishes this:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class JsonAnyPropertyNameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
}

class JsonAnyPropertyNameConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This converter is intended to be applied directly to a type or a property.");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            int defaultCount = 0;
            var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
            if (existingValue == null)
                existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.Comment:
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                        {
                            var name = reader.Value.ToString();
                            var property = contract.Properties.GetClosestMatchProperty(name);
                            if (!reader.Read())
                                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Missing value at path: {0}", reader.Path));
                            if (property == null)
                            {
                                property = contract.Properties.Where(p => p.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(true).OfType<JsonAnyPropertyNameAttribute>().Any()).Single();
                                defaultCount++;
                                if (defaultCount > 1)
                                {
                                    throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Too many properties with unknown names for type {0} at path {1}", objectType, reader.Path));
                                }
                            }
                            var value = serializer.Deserialize(reader, property.PropertyType);
                            property.ValueProvider.SetValue(existingValue, value);
                        }
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.EndObject:
                        return existingValue;
                    default:
                        throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unknown token {0} at path: {1} ", reader.TokenType, reader.Path));
                }
            }
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unclosed object at path: {0}", reader.Path));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is JsonException)
                throw;
            // Wrap any exceptions encountered in a JsonSerializationException
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Error deserializing type {0} at path {1}", objectType, reader.Path), ex);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then add it to your types as follows.  The `[JsonAnyPropertyName]` attribute indicates the c# property to which an unknown property should be deserialized.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonAnyPropertyNameConverter))]
public class ResponseData<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("total_count")]
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    [JsonAnyPropertyName]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Response<T> : Response
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public ResponseData<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

If there are multiple unknown properties, the converter throws an exception rather than overwriting the previously deserialized data.